Grounding a Chandelier Properly
The ceiling box has a ground copper wire coming from above the ceiling wrapped around a green screw and then extending downwards. The mounting bracket also has a green grounding screw. The chandeliers ground wire is not on the chandelier itself, it is on the mounting bracket body between a washer and nut on the cylindrical male connector to which the chandeliers chain end screws onto to hang from.
I took the end of the ground from the ceiling box that's hanging down and connected it to the chandelier's ground wire end with a wing nut connector and then wrapped the chandelier side ground wire around the green screw on the mounting bracket that is screwed into the ceiling box. That ground wire continues down and like I said above, ends in between a washer and a nut on the mounting bracket body cylinder shaped male part that screws into the chandeliers chain end to hang from.
Does this all sound like it was done correctly and is it safe?
Thank you for your help.

a picture would help

It sounds correct. As long as you have a constant ground path between the chandelier and the ground wire in the ceiling box, you are good.
